# Overriding JavaFX MediaPlayer class

Tags: javafx, media-player, rapidshare

I haven't tried it yet, but is it possible to extend JavaFX's Media class used in MediaPlayer class, content fetching part, to perform certain operation on file, before playing it in real-time? I would like to implement rapidshare fetch and decompress processor on content URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JavaFX class, since pure Java can use com.sun.media.jmc.JMediaPlayer with the same functionality.